# Calabash - how to compare text from label with given id?

Tags: ios, ruby, bdd, calabash, calabash-ios

I want to make assertion of the results of Calabash queries for labels with given ids. But the 'assert' method seems to not exist in Calabash. I test an iOS application.

My code:

```
Then(/^arrival date has been changed to day after departure date$/) do
    departure_date_day = query("label marked:'departure_date_day'", :text).first
    arrival_date_day = query("label marked:'arrival_date_day'", :text ()).first
    # assert arrival_date_day.to_i == departure_date_day.to_i + 1
end
```

How to do this?

Regards,

Michał

Comment: Why do you want to assert? To fail the test case? If so could consider using screenshot_and_raise. Where you can fail the test case and create a screenshot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These methods exist in the base Ruby stack rather than Calabash. You can find Ruby's assert methods here:
http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0/libdoc/minitest/rdoc/MiniTest/Assertions.html

More information is here:
https://github.com/seattlerb/minitest

Rather than use assert, I personally like Ruby's 'should' syntax. First install this gem:

```
gem install rspec-expectations
```

then in features/support/env.rb:

```
require 'rspec/expectations'
```

finally, you can assert like so:

```
departure_date_day.should eq query("label marked:'departure_date_day'", :text).first
```

Should has been deprecated in favor of expect(). I still prefer should ... more info is here: http://rspec.info/blog/2012/06/rspecs-new-expectation-syntax/